# Getting started with network programming in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, boost-asio

I just started a summer job at my university doing work in a lab, and I've been given a rather large, vague problem to tackle without much guidance so I was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction.

Essentially it's a 3-d world built in Qt using VTK (Visualization ToolKit) for use in therapy and rehab, and my task is to find a way to network two or more instances of the program so that users can share the same 3-d environment (essentially a networked video game).

The professor wants it to be secure, for latency to be as low as possible, and for the program to record data after a session is complete.

So far I was thinking (without much experience) of doing a client/server model built in Qt, but I'm not sure where to start.

**Q1:**
Should I use Boost.asio, or Qt library for networking?

**Q2:**
Are there any concepts I should be mindful of from the get-go for security, and network programming in general? (I've heard good things about [Beej's](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) Guide, and books by [W. Richard Stevens](http://www.amazon.ca/UNIX-Network-Programming-Richard-Stevens/dp/0139498761))

Comment: When choosing `Qt` you should use `Qt` features as much as possible, and retain mixing with other libraries (it might work though) IMHO. That's why I'm rarely using `Qt` so far. Anyway you still can layer your networking stack functionality by providing your own wrapper classes, for what you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to answer your first question, it depends on which platforms are you targeting (Windows, Linux, OSX...). You could use native OS socket api (bsd sockets or winsock) but Qt provides very good abstractions for these so for the sake of simplicity I would stick with it. I'm unfamiliar with boost.asio but I'm pretty sure that Qt could provide you with all you need disregarding the platform you intent to target.

As for the second question, you have to carefully analyze what kind of information you want to transmit and what will characterize the exchange.
If you intend to make it like a video game where players interact in real time, you are bound to use UDP sockets (although some data can go missing, it allows for "real time" communication). Control messages can circulate through TCP as the impact of latency won't be so critical and you want them to be reliably sent, so consider having two sockets (TCP and UDP) if that's the case, and use them for their purposes.

Those resources that you link are quite informative but assuming you have knowledge of TCP and UDP and their features, I would suggest you to brush up your multithreading skills. Qt offers you good infrastructure for this, but topics like Asynchronous I/O (how to implement selectable sockets) may help you to create a better design that will remove a lot of overhead from additional threads (specially for reading).

These are my 2 cents.

Good luck for your project, I'm sure it will be a good chance for you to learn and put some theory into practice.